# Apache 2.2 VirtualHosts and multiple ports

Tags: apache

I am seeing some interesting behavior with our webservers.

I've setup some https URLs using the VirtuaHosts Directives, and put them on non-standard ports.  I'm using ports 4443 and 4543.

So browsing to https://test-domain.com:4443 works, and so does https://test2-domain.com:4543.  However, if I type in test-domain2.com:4443 or test-domain.com:4445 that also takes you to the correct webpage by port. (When I'm testing I'm typing in the full link, stack overflow wouldn't let me type in more than two so i removed the https:// portion for the question).

Basically, as long as you pass a valid domain, you can put in either port and it takes you to the site hosted on that port.  I would think this behavior wouldn't be possible.  I would think if I typed Site A's domain with Site's B port I would get back a Not Found page or another error page, instead I'm always taken to site B.  Its resolving to whatever is hosted at the port.

If anyone has any suggestions or knows what Im doing wrong I'd appreciate the answer or help.

Here is the Apache config... 
I did look at the online apache documentation, and I tried experimenting by using the webserver IP address for NameVirtualHost and VirtualHost and that produced the same behavior

```
NameVirtualHost *:4443

<VirtualHost *:4443>
#SetEnv VHOST "test.domain.com"
ServerName test.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test/public
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile ssl/test.domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/test.domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile ssl/gd_bundle.crt
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

ErrorLog logs/test-error_log
CustomLog logs/test-access_log common
</VirtualHost>


NameVirtualHost *:4543

<VirtualHost *:4543>
#SetEnv VHOST "test2.domain.com"
ServerName test2.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/test2/public
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile ssl/test2.domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile ssl/test2.domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile ssl/gd_bundle.crt
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

ErrorLog logs/test2-error_log
CustomLog logs/test2-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Follow up, I've tried adding the following sections:
    
    Redirect 404 /
    ErrorDocument 404 "No Such Site.  Check the URL spelling.  Our main site is \
                  http://test1.domain.com/'>http:/test1.domain.com"

```
<VirtualHost *:4543>
Redirect 404 /
ErrorDocument 404 "No Such Site.  Check the URL spelling.  Our main site is \
              <a href='http://test2.domain.com/'>http://test2.domain.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

and apachectl -S shows the following:

```
*:4543                 is a NameVirtualHost
default server test2.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.https.conf:76)
port 4543 namevhost test2.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.https.conf:76)
port 4543 namevhost ip-10-0-1-204.ec2.internal (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.https.conf:92)
*:4443                 is a NameVirtualHost
default server test1.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.https.conf:51)
port 4443 namevhost test1.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.https.conf:51)
port 4443 namevhost ip-10-0-1-204.ec2.internal (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.https.conf:68)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
default server test.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.https.conf:20)
port 443 namevhost test.domain.com /etc/httpd/conf.d/test.https.conf:20)
port 443 namevhost ip-10-0-1-204.ec2.internal (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:76)
*:80                    is a NameVirtualHost
default server test.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.http.conf:3)
port 80 namevhost test.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.http.conf:3)
port 80 namevhost test1.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.http.conf:8)
port 80 namevhost test2.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.http.conf:13)
port 80 namevhost ip-10-0-1-204.ec2.internal (/etc/httpd/conf.d/test.http.conf:18)
    wild alias *.domain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache resolves virtual hosts in two phases.

First, it finds the best matching IP-based vhost looking only at the interface and port in the VirtualHost directive.

If there's more than 1 of the best match, when the request is available it picks the best name-based match from that IP-based best match.

You only have 1 VH for each set of name-based virtual hosts.

So once the IP-based vhost is selected at the connection level, there is no other selection to be made. It won't hop over to another set of NVH'es.

Comment: Ok, @covener so I tried added another vhost section to account for this but its still producing the same result.  
`<VirtualHost *:4543>
  Redirect 404 /
  ErrorDocument 404 "No Such Site.  Check the URL spelling.  Our main site is \
                    <a href='http://test2.domain.com/'>http://test2.domain.com"
</VirtualHost>  `

Comment: you added it _before_ the current one?  Is it inheriting the DocumentRoot from the global conf? Does apachectl -S give a clue?

Comment: No I added those after the current one.  apachectl -S shows the following:

Comment: See above in the original question post, I added the apachectl output as well as one of the Virtual Host stanzas I added.

Comment: Well if you add it after, the first-listed one will still be the default. You want a new default. Prepend the catch-alls.

Comment: Doing that produces an SSL Connection error...Correction, had to add the SSL info to that section, and then that worked, thanks much.